# How to click one by one to get data from website by using selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to get data from the website but I want to select first 1000 link open one by one and get data from there.

I have tried:

```
list_links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

for i in list_links:
        print (i.get_attribute('href'))
```

through this getting extra links which are not required.

for example: `https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1,2,3,4,5,%3E5&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment,Residential-House,Villa,Residential-Plot&cityName=Mumbai`

we will get more than 50k link. How to open only first 1000 link has in below with properties photos.

**Edit**

I have tried this also:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='.l-srp__results.flex__item']")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')

for matches in driver:
    print('Liking')
    print (matches)
    #matches.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

But getting error: `TypeError: 'WebDriver' object is not iterable`

Why I am not getting link by using this line: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')`

**Edit 1**

I am trying to sort links as per below but getting error

```
            result = re.findall(r'https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/', my_list)
            print (result)
```

Error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

or Tried

```
            a = ['https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/']
            output_names = [name for name in a if (name[:45] in my_list)]
            print (output_names)
```

Not getting anything.

All links are in list. Please suggest

Thank you in advance. Please suggest

Comment: Can you give us an example of links you do want? You'll need to refine your selector.

Comment: Please open this link `https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1,2,3,4,5,%3E5&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment,Residential-House,Villa,Residential-Plot&cityName=Mumbai` and here you will get more than 50000 property details and click first one `https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/2-BHK-1182-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Kandivali-East-in-Mumbai&id=4d423336313032373731` and then you will see some data like bedrooms, Bathroom etc.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is not a good idea for web scraping. I would suggest you to use JMeter which is FREE and Open Source.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-how-to-do-web-scraping/

If you want to use selenium, the approach you are trying to follow is not a stable approach - clicking and grabbing the data. Instead I would suggest you to follow this - something similar here. The example is in java. But you could get the idea.

```
driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com");

Map<Integer, List<String>> map = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@href]")) 
                .stream()                             // find all elements which has href attribute & process one by one
                .map(ele -> ele.getAttribute("href")) // get the value of href
                .map(String::trim)                    // trim the text
                .distinct()                           // there could be duplicate links , so find unique
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LinkUtil::getResponseCode)); // group the links based on the response code
```

More info is here.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-find-broken-links-on-a-page/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should collect all the elements in list which having tag name "a" with "href" properties which is not null. 
Then traverse through the list and click on element one by one.
Create a list of type WebElement and store all the valid links. 
Here you can apply more filters or conditions i.e. link contains some characters or some other condition.

To Store the WebElement in list you can use **driver.findEelements()** this method will return list of type WebElement.

Comment: how to sort link? I need only some valid link. Please suggest

Comment: In this case I guess give your data like. what you mean by valid link and what you mean by invalid link ? . give example.